# C++/CLR: command-line error only when compiling x86

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I'm building a project that uses C++/CLI to wrap a C# dll. Everything works just fine when compiled in x64. Debug & release both work on x64. 
When I switch to x86, however, I get the following error:

> command-line error: cannot open metadata file "D:\path\to\CppWrapper\CsLibrary.dll"

...followed up with the list of "name must be a namespace" errors you would expect after a library link has failed.

I've been going around and around in the individual project settings to no success.

Comment: I bet your build output paths are different for x86 and x64 builds. And you should use a relative path for the references.

Comment: Thanks! That was one of my problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I eventually gave up and went through the csproj files one by one for every project in the solution to make sure all the build outputs were pointed the right way. I've managed to solve this issue and have moved on to the next issue.

Who would have thought switching from x64 to x86 would be such a mess?